# Set dynamic state name based on the delivered parameter in react-native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, state

I'm new to developing in react-native. Right now I'm trying to code a simple Scoreboard for the Dart game "Cricket" to get my feet wet.

It is basically a game where you need to hit the 15-20 and bullseye fields 3 times to close them. If you hit them more than 3 times you can collect points.

My first version of the app is working but its ugly and uses lots lines of code. I made a function for every point field (15-20 + bullseye) to add the points. Like:

```
tap20(){

this.state.indicator = "x";

if(this.state.tapped_20 > 1){
    this.state.indicator = "xx";
if(this.state.tapped_20 > 2){
  this.state.indicator = "xxx";
  if(this.state.tapped_20 > 3){
  this.state.points = 20 + this.state.points

  }
}
}

this.setState({

points: this.state.points,
tapped_20: this.state.tapped_20+1,
})
}

tap19(){

this.state.indicator_19 = "x";

if(this.state.tapped_19 > 1){
    this.state.indicator_19 = "xx";
if(this.state.tapped_19 > 2){
  this.state.indicator_19 = "xxx";
  if(this.state.tapped_19 > 3){
  console.log("Ab hier Punkte..")
  this.state.points = 19 + this.state.points

  }
}
}

this.setState({

points: this.state.points,
tapped_19: this.state.tapped_19+1,
})
}
```

Etc.. My approach was now to overgive an parameter with the function. So i just have one function which adds the points based on the given parameter. Like so:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
onPress={this.testfunc.bind(this, 20)}
underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}> 20 Test</Text>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

Which calls the the function:

```
testfunc(i) {

  window['this.state.indicator_' + i ] = 'test'

  console.log(this.state.indicator_20)
...
```

When i debug it in the Browser it states that the console.log(this.state.indicator_20) is undefined.

It seems it does not work with this.state... Does anyone know how to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should never have to refer to `window` in React Native.  Consider that a red flag.

Second, you cannot evaluate the properties on objects in this fashion:  `window['this.state.indicator_' + i ]`.  You refer to a property called "foo" on an object called "bar" thusly: `bar['foo']` and you cannot reference any deeper (that is, no `bar['foo.baz']`).

Anyway, react provides `setState` for this:

```
testfunc(i) {
  const update = {};

  update['indicator_' + i] = 'test';

  this.setState(update);
}
```

Then refer to `this.state.indicator_X` in your render, and it'll update as expected.

Comment: Thank you Adam this is working. But now i ran into the next pitfall.

I wanted to set my tapped variable to the current state like in this example:

`updatet['tapped_' + i] = this.state.tapped_20+1;`

I tried to insert the variable i with different expressions but it returns me either an string or an NaN error. For example:

 `updatet['tapped_' + i] = ['this.state.tapped_'+i]+1;`

Comment: @RiseAgainst Sorry to say, `['this.state.tapped_'+i]+1` is total nonsense in JavaScript.  Please read up on [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: but still how do I access that state in same way ? like this.state.indicator_ + i ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is: `this.state['tapped_' + i]` or `this.state['tapped_${i}']`